# HCE: code entry point for unfiltered incoming APDU

Tags: java, android, nfc, hce

I'm having trouble finding orientation in the Android 4.4.4 source responsible for NFC Host Card Emulation (HCE).

In particular I'm looking for an entry point, i.e. class or method at which I can tap in and listen to all incoming command APDUs unfiltered.
I thought `HostEmulationManager.onHostEmulationData(byte[] apdu)` provides such a place but unfortunately I find that some fully ISO 7816-4 compliant APDUs won't even get there. I then receive something like

`02-12 17:39:32.598: E/BrcmNfcNfa(878): CET4T: Application has not been selected
 02-12 17:48:03.867: E/BrcmNfcNfa(878): UICC[0x0] is not activated`

without the method ever being called.

Any ideas where to start?
I don't want to delve into C-Code so the point of access should be anywhere in Java.

Answer (score 0):

If you need an entry point for NFC Host Card Emulation (HCE), look in the direction of the HostApduService class and in particular processCommandApdu method.